# (Xamarin) Bind data from multiple classes to one ListView?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build a ListView that draws data from two SQLite tables. One is a Header table and the other is a Detail table. The Header table has an Id field that acts as a primary key, and it has a one-to-many relationship with the Detail table (this Id field is the only column that both tables share).

My ListView in theory would have the Header table's Id displayed inside a ViewCell, and when tapped would expand and display all Detail table rows with the same Id. The issue is, I don't know how to set the Listview's ItemsSource to draw from both tables, and obviously SQLite doesn't accept `List<Table>` as a valid property. As far as the expanding/collapsing action, I think setting the ViewCell's HeightRequest in the tapped event handler is the method I'll try, but please don't hesitate to share any techniques or code snippets you may have used to do this previously.

Edit: @iSpain17 here is my code as per the last snippet on iSpain17's answer. The error that the XAML editor gives me is "The property 'ElementTemplateContent' is set more than once."

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding HeaderDetailsList}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding HeaderId}"/>
                            <CollectionView>
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextCell Text="{Binding DetailsPart1}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

Comment: You can use the plugin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfListView/17.3.0.9-beta .And you can get your free license for our complete product offering by signing in with LinkedIn or XING. https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense

Comment: I don't know what you can get from the Community Edition of Syncfusion, but their Listview has a template for Header, Footer and LoadMore, it solves almost every problem of the common ListView (just like the one you described), see their examples here: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/overview, if the community edition lets you use their ListView, i would go with it.
Extra Tip: this is what you are looking for probably: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/grouping#group-expand-and-collapse

Comment: I'm experimenting with Syncfusion's ListView control now and it seems to be suiting my needs, however the documentation isn't exactly very clear on how grouping works, much less how I'd go about grouping with my particular data scenario. Any advice?

Comment: @Nick you have luck that i stumble in this post again, since you didn't mentioned any of the people that commented on this, the last link on my comment its what you need, and if you follow all the docummentation on the Grouping (https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/grouping), you will notice that you can declare the header separator by 
<data:DataSource>
        <data:DataSource.GroupDescriptors>
          <data:GroupDescriptor PropertyName="BookName"/>
        </data:DataSource.GroupDescriptors>
</data:DataSource>
but there's other ways to do it, just take an hour to read all

Comment: the info about the grouping part of the Syncfusion ListView

Comment: I don't understand why you can't draw data from multiple tables and present them in a ListView, that's not something that's impossible. Create a ViewModel exclusively for this listview (e.g. LVViewModel), collect your data into it, and then set a List<LVViewModel> as the ItemSource.

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais I have spent some time with Syncfusion customer support and they've informed me that their ListView control has no capability to do what my question asks.

Comment: @iSpain17 Could you walk me through that please? Any links to examples of doing that?

Comment: Check my answer. If you provide more details based on it, we can work on it further together.

Comment: it seems very strange that syncfusion doesnt have suport for it when i did it when developing an app were i needed a header for Staff and other for Team and expand it with the members of it, what may be the problem is that the coumunity version doesnt have that, wich i doubt it, can you link me the ticket? also the @iSpain17 anwser seems good, but i can't confirm it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't exactly provide your own code, so I can only guess:

You create a class e.g. HeaderDetails (obviously just a draft):

```
class HeaderDetails : BindableObject {

    public List<Detail> DetailsForThisId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public HeaderDetails(int headerId) {
       Id = headerId;
       DetailsForThisId = GetDetailItemsForId(headerId); //This method queries your SQLite details table based on given Id.
    }

}
```

Then your main ViewModel for the page has a `List<HeaderDetails>`:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    [...]
    private ObservableCollection headerDetailsList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<HeaderDetails> HeaderDetailList {
        get => headerDetailsList;
        set {
            headerDetailsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    [...]

    public ViewModel() {
        [...]
        var _headerDetailList = new List<HeaderDetails>();
        var headerIds = QueryAllHeaderIds() //Should return a list of all header Ids in your SQLite header table.

        foreach(var headerId in headerIds) {
             _headerDetailsList.Add(new HeaderDetails(headerId));
        }

        HeaderDetailList = new ObservableCollection(_headerDetailList);
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML file (please use CollectionView)

```
<CollectionView ItemSource="{Binding HeaderDetailsList}" [...]>
  [...]
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!-- Your inner View (StackLayout, etc.) --> 
      [...]
      <CollectionView ItemSource="{Binding DetailsForThisId}" [...]>
        [...]
      </CollectionView>
      [...]
    </DataTemplate>
  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help: however on the XAML side CollectionView won't let me nest one inside the another like that?

Comment: Still not allowing nesting with ItemTemplate and DataTemplate in that format.

Comment: Could you add your code? It's kinda hard to help without seeing your actual code.

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements as DataTemplate. Wrap it in a StackLayout (as you see it in my above line: `<!-- Your inner View (StackLayout, etc.) -->`) meaning that DataTemplate has to be a *single* view.